# Asking question linked to paper/thesis

Tags: discussion

I was wondering whether it is allowed to ask a question concerning linguistics asking for feedback on linguistics.stackexchange but also requesting input on an external survey. This survey would be linked to adcademic research that is done in context of a bachelor paper or master thesis.

An example: let's say I am interested in how native English speakers tend to pronounce a certain order of sounds. I can ask a question here on StackExchange "How do native speakers pronounce this or that" and additionally in that question I would give a link to an external poll in which native speakers can choose from a number of options how they pronounce the sounds. The data that is received from this poll is then used for research. So, the question itself is completely applicable to the SE model, but I am wondering if that link to an external poll is allowed, because to some it might seem like spam.

Comment: Hello Bram. Thanks for asking but I'm not sure I totally understood your question... In general though, I don't think a thesis is a problem as long as the question is about Linguistics and is properly worded to fit the StackExchange model (no polls, no opinion-based questions, etc).

Comment: @Alenanno I'll give an example: say I am interested in how native English speakers tend to pronounce a certain order of sounds. I can ask a question "How do native speakers pronounce this or that" and additionally in that question I give a link to an external poll in which native speakers can choose from a number of options how they pronounce the sounds. So, the question itself is completely applicable to the SE model, but I am wondering if that link to an external poll is allowed, because to some it might seem like spam. The data that is received from this poll is then used for research.